# How to properly install the Python application package on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: python, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a Python app on Elastic Beanstalk. I know how to install *other* Python requirements (i.e using `requirements.txt`), but I am unsure the best way to install the application package itself.

My project structure is as follows:

```
project
|- .ebextensions/
|- .platform
|- requirements.txt
|- pyproject.toml
|- Procfile
|- src/
|  |- package
|  |  |- __init__.py
|  |  |- file.py
```

The `Procfile` looks like this:

```
web: uvicorn package.main:app --workers=4 --port 8000
```

and the pyproject.toml installs the package correctly (locally), such that I can do
`python -c "import package"` without error (from any directory).

However, the application fails to deploy with errors such as

```
<time> <ip> web[9080]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package'
```

I tried putting a pre-deploy script in `.platform/hooks/predeploy/pip.sh` that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate
pip install -e .
chown -R webapp .
chown -R webapp /var/app/venv/
```

It runs without error (checking `/var/log/eb-hooks.log`) but it doesn't seem to fix the error. Weirdly enough, I see my package on `pip list` but importing it raises an error.

If I `eb ssh` in, and sudo run the above script, it works and I can run the app without issue as the `webapp` user, which is even more confusing! However, I still cannot have a working app after `eb deploy` unless I manually go in and run the script.

This leads me to the following questions:

1. What is the right way to do this? This seems like a very convoluted way to do a very simple thing.
2. Why doesn't the script work as a pre-deploy script?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: you can include local path dependencies in your `requirements.txt` e.g:

This installs the package and a subpackage:

```
file: .
file: ./subpackage
```

However, make sure that you don't read in the requirements.txt in your setup.py or similar!